# how to make an GUI OS with C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, operating-system

I would like to know how to make an GUI OS using C# (becuose it`s the language I know the best).

- I would like to make it as most as my own.

I know that a good start is to to help to improve completed OS (like a Cosmos) but I would like to do that part of the job by myself. What have the done? How did they made that(boot and  some more things)???That is a thing I don`t know.

Comment: Tell you what, let's head to the bar and we can talk about it over a(bout a million) beer(s); because it will take that long.  NOTE:  You're buying...

Comment: [Cosmos is open source](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/). Start there.

Comment: @p.s.w.g : pretty cool ... I´ll go deeper into that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The [help] says in part about what you shouldn't ask here: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.". Your question is wide enough in scope a book could be written about it. See [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An operating system usually takes years of work by a team of people.  Moreover, you cannot do this with C#, as it's too high level to realistically facilitate the type of development you're talking about.